# Event Viewer: atapi errors

Tags: windows-xp, netbook, sp3, event-log

Specs for Samsung N120 Netbook

Atom N270 @ 1.60 GHz / 160 GB IDE HDD / 2 GB PC2-5300 DDR2 RAM / Windows XP Home SP3

So I'm still getting some atapi errors in my Event Viewer. Here are two atapi errors I am getting over and over again:

(1) The device, \Device\Ide\IdePort0, did not respond within the timeout period. (2) The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort0.

In addition, I am repeatedly getting this warning as well:

(1) An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk0\D during a paging operation.

I just got this back from repair, where before, I couldn't boot at all because I was led to a black screen saying "Operating System Not Found". Still, I got it back and it can boot again, without any hard drive replacement or data loss.

So, how can I get rid of these errors and warnings? What could have happened during repairs to allow my netbook to boot again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors could be the result of a few things, it depends on what you have in the IDE0 port.

Possibilities:

- There are problems with the IDE0 port on your motherboard
- There are problems with your hard drive or CD/DVD drive
- Software error

these are the main causes, there are others.

Check out the corresponding EventID.net pages, specifically [Event ID 9](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=9&eventno=2060&source=atapi&phase=1) and [Event ID 51](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=51&eventno=793&source=Disk&phase=1).

Comment: You gave this same answer on a similar question about my netbook a month or so ago. But I can eliminate the 4th bullet, simply because there are no cables connecting a hard drive to the motherboard in a netbook, especially. I can also eliminate the 1st one because I don't have any optical drives. So, for (2), (4) and (5), how could I tell?

Comment: Yes, a very similar answer indeed! For the first 2, you could test a different CD drive. A Linux LiveCD will also help in diagnosis. IF a different OS is also having problems with the device, that could rule out software issues on XP. Have you tried reading CDs lately?

Comment: Nope. I don't have an optical drive and I only borrow a friend's external USB DVD burner. Last time I used it was more than 2 weeks ago when I installed Office 07.

Comment: Ah. That leaves motherboard and hard drive. Do you have another drive to test in there?

Comment: I don't have another drive to test, and I'd preferably not open up my netbook on my own. Also, I just sent in my netbook for repair and they didn't even detect any errors. I'm pretty sure it's the hard drive itself, but they didn't do anything. Will contact Samsung Support again...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help. Best of luck!

Comment: Oh wait, maybe you can help me now. I failed to mention that often times when my netbook is in Stand-by, it starts back up on its own with an error dialog box saying "An I/O device has reported an I/O error." Would you think it is actually the motherboard's IDE controller causing the issues now?

Comment: It very well could be. I'd still get Samsung to take a look at it to be entirely safe.